# Powers of coefficients divide the resultant

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinant

Let $f(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots+a_n$, $g(x)=b_0x^m+b_1x^{m-1}+\dots+b_m$, with coefficients in a field. Prove that $a_0^mb_m^n$ divides the resultant of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

I have written the resultant as a determinant, I see that $a_0^mb_m^n$ is the product over the main diagonal, but I don't know how to proceed further. I tried Laplace expansion but it didn't help.

Comment: You should clear up your notation with the coefficients. You messed something up. Furthermore, what do you mean by "divides"? You said, you work over a field.

Comment: where is $b_m$ in your polinomials? Maybe all the coefficients of $g(x)$ are $b_i$ ?

Comment: Read [this](http://planetmath.org/proofthatsylvestersmatrixequalstheresultant).